# unable to connect to ssl server Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown and ReadDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have a situation where client A should connect to server B and server B should connect to server C.and connection must be of secure socket.

I tried and successfully established connection b/w A to B and B to C individually.But when i tried to establish connection simultaneously to A to B and B to C it is raising error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:916)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at VfSer.main(VfSer.java:51)
```

Here is the code which i tried and i used two different certificates for A to B and B to C connection.

here is the A code

```
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "vaserkey");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreSSN", "123456");
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
//.....
}
```

here is the B code

```
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "vaserkey");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
            //adding ssl layer to socket connection
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =(SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =(SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            //taking infinite connection one by one
            while(true){
            //accepting incoming connection
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();//....
}catch(Exception e){}
        //after receiving data trying to establish connection with C
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "vfserkey");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreSSN", "123456");
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory1 = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket1 = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory1.createSocket(ip, port);
```

//..sending data to C
here is the C code:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "vfserkey");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
    try {
        //adding ssl layer to socket connection
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =(SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =(SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

      SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
```

//getting the connection and receiving the data from C
}
and finally here is the tool which i used to generate the certificates .

```
keytool -genkey vaserkey -keyalg RSA
keytool -genkey vfserkey -keyalg RSA
```

sorry if i have said any thing wrong I'am new to SSL programming please correct me if iam wrong..

Comment: "0 down vote favorite"?

Comment: sorry sir. i didn't get you.
am i done any thing wrong.

Comment: Why did you put "0 down vote favorite" at the beginning of your post?

Comment: sorry sir .it was my mistake .i didn't observe that.

Comment: It means they copy and pasted it from another post, possibly one that's been closed and / or deleted. @CupawnTae

Comment: yes sir i copied .and it was my post .i posted 2 days back. but i haven't got solved .and i am new to here ..sir please i need help on this problem i don't to whom to ask.sorry if i am done any thing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i'am posting the answer which might help full to others.

I modified the code as suggested  by ***@dave_thompson_085***

> Set all SSL properties first. DefaultSSLContext is used by default by
>   both SSLSocketFactory and SSLServerSocketFactory, but it is
>   constructed only the first time is it used. Changing any of the
>   relevant system properties, or the files they point to, after that
>   first use is ignored and has no effect. So you need to set all
>   javax.net.ssl.* properties before calling either factory.

```
i replaced 
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =(SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
with 
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =(SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSocketFactory();
```

here is the A code

```
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "vaserkey");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreSSN", "123456");
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory =  (SSLSocketFactory) SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
//.....
}
```

here is the B code

```
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "vaserkey");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
            //adding ssl layer to socket connection
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSocketFactory();                SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =(SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            //taking infinite connection one by one
            while(true){
            //accepting incoming connection
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();//....
}catch(Exception e){}
        //after receiving data trying to establish connection with C
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "vfserkey");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreSSN", "123456");
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory1 = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLSocket sslsocket1 = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory1.createSocket(ip, port);
```

//..sending data to C
here is the C code:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "vfserkey");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
    try {
        //adding ssl layer to socket connection
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =((SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSocketFactory();           SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =(SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

      SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();//getting the connection and receiving the data from C}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Set all SSL properties first.** `DefaultSSLContext` is used by default by both `SSLSocketFactory` and `SSLServerSocketFactory`, but it is constructed only the first time is it used. Changing any of the relevant system properties, or the files they point to, *after* that first use is ignored and has no effect. So you need to set *all* `javax.net.ssl.*` properties before calling *either* factory.

Also:

Those keytool commands can't have been copied correctly. You need `-keystore` before the filename on each one. And they generate both privatekeys *and* (selfsigned) certificates; you can't generate only a certificate and if you could it would be unusable for pretty much anything including SSL/TLS. 
Finally, the preferred operation is now `-genkeypair`; the spelling `-genkey` is supported for backward comptability, but may eventually get dropped.

**It's unwise to use keystore (entry) for truststore.** While the TrustManager logic does find and use the cert in a privatekey entry (see above), copying the keystore (or just the privatekey entry/ies) to relier(s)/client(s) is poor practice. [edit] Anyone who gets your privatekey can often impersonate you, with results including stealing your sensitive data and other resources such as money. Even if a particular client is not malicious, they are rarely motivated to be as careful of your keys as you are, and if there are many clients, who may have multiple machines, backups, replacements, virtualization, outsourcing, testing, temps, contractors, etc. this risk is multiplied.

The correct/better way is to export *only* the certificate from the server keystore, and import *only* the certificate to the client truststore (in "Java KeyStore" format, but not actually a key) something like:

```
 keytool -keystore vaserkey -exportcert -file vasercert
 keytool -keystore vasertrust -importcert -file vasercert
 # same again for vf...
 # use vasertrust for A-trust and vfserTrust for B-trust in your example
```

Comment: Copying the private key anywhere, even via a keystore, is *already* a copy, and it is already a *prima facie* security breach, even before the possible consequences you mention. Another major consequence is that the recipient can now impersonate you.

Comment: @EJP a copy that *you* control is not a breach, but anyone else *usually* is, editted. Also note it isn't clear to me if this OP is copying at all, or just running all three programs in one place (using the same actual files, not just contents) which is often convenient for testing.